# How to handle a dictionary with GraphQL .NET?

Tags: .net-core, graphql

I want to retrieve data via GraphQL in .NET.

I have an object, that has a `Dictionary<String, Int>` property.

Retrieving basic fields like string and int works with my current setup, but I did not find a way to let GraphQL use the dictionary directly.

My idea now was to convert the dictionary into a list, either via `ToList()`, or via something like a `MyTupleType`, that would store the key-value-pairs of the dictionary.

```cs
public class MyTupleType : ObjectGraphType<MyTupleDto>
{
   public MyTupleType()
   {
      Field<StringGraphType>(dto => dto.Key);
      Field<IntGraphType>(dto => dto.Value);
   }
}

public class ExampleType : ObjectGraphType<ExampleDto>
{
    public ProductType()
    {
       Field<ListGraphType<MyTupleType>>(name: "tuples", expression: dto => dto.MyDictionary);
    }
}
```

My question: is there a better/preferred way to do this?

Is there a way to do it with the direct use of the dictionary?
I would like to avoid having to convert my DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to retrieve a property from your Dictionary, you can follow these steps. First, create a class called `KeyValuePairGraphType` that extends `ObjectGraphType<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`:

```cs
public class KeyValuePairGraphType<TKey, TValue> : ObjectGraphType<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public KeyValuePairGraphType()
    {
        Field(p => p.Key);
        Field(p => p.Value);
    }
}
```

Next, when defining the type, use the `Field` method and specify `YourDictionary` as the property name. Set the `type` parameter to `typeof(ListGraphType<KeyValuePairGraphType<string, int>>)`, and make sure to set `nullable` to `true` if needed:

```cs
Field(t => t.YourDictionary, type: typeof(ListGraphType<KeyValuePairGraphType<string, int>>), nullable: true);
```

This will allow you to retrieve the Dictionary property and represent it as a list of key-value pairs.